# Java: reading from an input file, then moving data into subclasses

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass, simulation

Early stages of a simulation project, when this program runs, its supposed to read in a file such as the one below, then it should process each neuron and synapse through the program. There are two types of synapse, unnamed synapses and named ones. Synapse X above is a named synapse connecting neurons A and B. Unnamed synapses have a single dash in the name field. Neuron and synapse names be non-numeric. Any synapse that is named may be the target of a secondary synapse. The synapse B X above is a secondary synapse that connects neuron B to (primary) synapse X. A synapse can be named or unnamed has two subclasses: Primary and Secondary.

**My question:** This code is part of a semester project, the first few parts were not difficult, but I'm unsure about subclasses. How do I scan in the synapse line and determine which belongs in subclass Primary and which ones belong in Secondary? Should I do something to the InitializeNetwork method or do I need something somewhere else?

**Sample Input File:***

```
neuron A 1.0 0.95
neuron B 1.0 0.0
synapse X A B 1.2  0.5
synapse - B A 0.3 -0.5
synapse - B X 0.3  0.5
```

**The code I have so far:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

// Utility classes

/** Error reporting methods
 */
class Errors {
    static void fatal( String message ) {
        System.err.println( "Fatal error: " + message );
        System.exit( 1 );
    }
    static void warning( String message ) {
        System.err.println( "Error: " + message );
    }
}

/** Input scanning support methods
 */
class ScanSupport {
    /** Force there to be a line end here, complain if not
     */
    static void lineEnd( Scanner sc, String message ) {
        String skip = sc.nextLine();
        if (!"".equals( skip )) {
            // Bug:  do we want to allow comments here
            Errors.warning( message + " -- expected a newline" );
        }
        // Bug:  what if sc.nextLine() was illegal (illegal state)
    }

    /** Get the next float, or complain if there isn't one
     */
    static String nextName( Scanner sc, String message ) {
        if (sc.hasNext( "[a-zA-Z]\\w*" )) {
            return sc.next();
        } else {
            Errors.warning( message + " -- expected a name" );
            return null;
        }
    }

    /** Get the next float, or complain if there isn't one
     */
    static float nextFloat( Scanner sc, String message ) {
        if (sc.hasNextFloat()) {
            return sc.nextFloat();
        } else {
            Errors.warning( message + " -- expected a number" );
            return 99.99f;
        }
    }
}

// Simulation classes

/** Neurons are the vertices in the neuron network
 *  @see Synapse
 */
class Neuron {
    String name;            // name of this neuron
    private float threshold;    // voltage at which the neuron fires
    private float voltage;      // voltage at the given time
    private float time;     // (see above)

    private LinkedList <Synapse> synapses;  // the outputs of this neuron

    public class IllegalNameException extends Exception {}

    // initializer
    public Neuron( Scanner sc ) throws IllegalNameException {
        // scan and process one neuron
        name = ScanSupport.nextName( sc, "Neuron ??" );
        if (name == null) {
            sc.nextLine();
            throw new IllegalNameException();
        }
        if (NeuronNetwork.findNeuron( name ) != null) {
            Errors.warning(
                "Neuron " + name + " -- duplicate declaration"
            );
            sc.nextLine();
            throw new IllegalNameException();
        }
        threshold = ScanSupport.nextFloat( sc, "Neuron " + name );
        voltage = ScanSupport.nextFloat( sc, "Neuron " + name );
        time = 0.0f;
        ScanSupport.lineEnd( sc, "Neuron " + name );
    }

    // other methods
    public String toString() {
        return (
            "Neuron " +
            name +
            " " +
            threshold +
            " " +
            voltage
        );
    }
}

/** Synapses join neurons
 *  @see Neuron
 */
class Synapse {
    Neuron source;
    Neuron destination;
    Float delay;
    Float strength;

    // name is source destination

    public Synapse( Scanner sc ) {
        // scan and process one synapse
        String sourceName = ScanSupport.nextName( sc, "Synapse ??" );
        String dstName = ScanSupport.nextName( sc,
            "Synapse " +
            ( sourceName != null ? sourceName : "??" ) +
            " ??"
        );
        delay = ScanSupport.nextFloat( sc,
            "Synapse " +
            ( sourceName != null ? sourceName : "??" ) +
            " " +
            ( dstName != null ? dstName : "??" ) +
            " ??"
        );
        strength = ScanSupport.nextFloat( sc,
            "Synapse " +
            ( sourceName != null ? sourceName : "??" ) +
            " " +
            ( dstName != null ? dstName : "??" ) +
            " " + delay + " ??"
        );
        ScanSupport.lineEnd( sc,
            "Synapse " +
            ( sourceName != null ? sourceName : "??" ) +
            " " +
            ( dstName != null ? dstName : "??" ) +
            delay + " " + strength
        );

        // check correctness of fields
        source = NeuronNetwork.findNeuron( sourceName );
        if (source == null) {
            Errors.warning(
                "Synapse " +
                ( sourceName != null ? sourceName : "??" ) +
                " " +
                ( dstName != null ? dstName : "??" ) +
                " -- no such source"
            );
        }
        destination = NeuronNetwork.findNeuron( dstName );
        if (destination == null) {
            Errors.warning(
                "Synapse " +
                ( sourceName != null ? sourceName : "??" ) +
                " " +
                ( dstName != null ? dstName : "??" ) +
                " -- no such destination"
            );
        }
        if (delay < 0.0f) {
            Errors.warning(
                "Synapse " +
                ( sourceName != null ? sourceName : "??" ) +
                " " +
                ( dstName != null ? dstName : "??" ) +
                " " + delay + " " + strength +
                " -- illegal negative delay"
            );
            delay = 99.99f;
        }
    }

    // other methods
    public String toString() {
        return (
            "Synapse " +
            ( source != null ? source.name : "---" ) +
            " " +
            ( destination != null ? destination.name : "---" ) +
            " " + delay + " " + strength
        );
    }
}

/** NeuronNetwork is the main class that builds the whole model
 *  @see Neuron
 *  @see Synapse
 */
public class NeuronNetwork {

    // the sets of all neurons and all synapses
    static LinkedList <Neuron> neurons
        = new LinkedList <Neuron> ();
    static LinkedList <Synapse> synapses
        = new LinkedList <Synapse> ();

    /** Look up s in neurons, find that Neuron if it exists
     *  return null if not.
     */
    public static Neuron findNeuron( String s ) {
        for (Neuron n: neurons) {
            if (n.name.equals(s)) {
                return n;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /** Initialize the neuron network by scanning its description
     */
    static void initializeNetwork( Scanner sc ) {
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String command = sc.next();
            if ("neuron".equals( command )) {
                try {
                    neurons.add( new Neuron( sc ) );
                } catch (Neuron.IllegalNameException e) {
                    // no action required
                }
            } else if ("synapse".equals( command )) {
                synapses.add( new Synapse( sc ) );
            } else {
                Errors.warning( command + " -- what is that" );
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }

    /** Print out the neuron network from the data structure
     */
    static void printNetwork() {
        for (Neuron n:neurons) {
            System.out.println( n.toString() );
        }
        for (Synapse s:synapses) {
            System.out.println( s.toString() );
        }
    }

    /** Main program
     * @see initializeNetwork
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length < 1) {
                Errors.fatal( "-- missing file name" );
            }
            if (args.length > 1) {
                Errors.fatal( "-- too many arguments" );
            }
            initializeNetwork( new Scanner(new File(args[0])) );
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Errors.fatal( "" + args[0] + " -- file not found" );
        }
        printNetwork();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would question if you really want to use inheritance here.  It might be a better idea to use composition, where the behavior of synapses are defined by the classes that compose it.  Look into the **Strategy Pattern**, it will probably end up working much better than some inheritance hierarchy.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

Comment: I understand that but I'm trying to learn how inheritance works.