# I cannot get how ScanSupport is used. Any explanation?

Tags: java

I am debugging the following code but I cannot figure how ScanSupport is used.

```
public static void initializeTernary( Scanner sc ) {
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            // until we hit the end of the file
            String command = ScanSupport.nextName( sc );
            if ("gate".equals( command )) {
                Gate g = Gate.newGate( sc );
                if (g != null) gates.add( g );
```

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and add the relevant details to your question.

Comment: What is `ScanSupport`?  It is not a standard Java class.

Comment: Is your ScanSupport class from here? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857361/java-reading-from-an-input-file-then-moving-data-into-subclasses